# Odoo ERP not working on the Public IP cloud platform

Tags: ip, port, ubuntu-14.04, erp

I'm working on ubuntu server 15.04 on Digital Ocean and I've installed Odoo ERP from github alongside with all the required libraries, packages, postgresql ...etc and have followed all the steps in order to set it up on my DO IP. The current situation is when I access it at http://188.166.125.13:8069/ I get an internal server error. As long as I can tell from the terminal after executing the command ./openerp-server --addonspath=addons from inside the Odoo directory everything seems to be working fine, except that it seems to be reading the config locally executing 0.0.0.0 instead of my IP. Any clue about how to launch the application through the public IP and not locally?

Another question, is there a way to execute the droplet physically as backup so that I can reload it on any other server?

Answer (score 0):

First please check your local IP config.
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
Next please check that your Apache server allows connection from outside.
First of all please make sure "Apache default page" serves to outside world. Here is guide for Laravel(apache section guide works for Odoo ERP)
https://www.dev-metal.com/install-laravel-4-ubuntu-12-04-lts/
As I checked last time you can't  backup droplet from Digital ocean and reload to another server.